# Does append work only for the first found element?

Tags: jquery, html, append

Does `append` work only for the first found `element`?

```
<div id='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
<div id='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div> 

$('#parent').append('Text inside div');
```

I could see `Text inside div` printed only once when I run the html.

PS :
This works :

```
$('#parent>strong').append('Text inside div');
```

It prints the text twice.

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique** - so use class instead of id to group similar elements

Comment: it is already working as you want because you are using ID so it will automatically applied on first found child, if you use ID selector jquery code is automatically applied on first found element http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/duhLnq0s/4/     and yes for good programming ID must be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes instead of id, because ID **must** be unique

```js
$('.parent').append('Text inside div');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
<div class='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
```

Comment: Okay, but it does work for `(#parent>strong)`! it prints twice.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Quirk of `querySelectorAll` on whatever browser you happened to do that with. jQuery optimizes `#xyz` selectors into calls to `getElementById` because that's **really** fast, and other selectors to `querySelectorAll`. But the behavior you're seeing is undefined. It could easily append not at all, or just once. The behavior is undefined, because (again) using the same `id` on more than one element is invalid, creating an invalid document. What browsers do with invalid documents is (mostly) up to them.

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique.`$('#parent')` will only return first element in matched set. You need to use common class selector instead:

```
 <div class='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
 <div class='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
```

**JS:**

```
 $('.parent').append('Text inside div');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use same Id for more than one html element script picks the first one it encountered in flow.

Answer (score 0):

**Remember : ID's are unique**

- Each element can have only one ID
- Each page can have only one element with that ID

**Classes are NOT unique**

- You can use the same class on multiple elements.
- You can use multiple classes on the same element.

So what you need is :

```
<div class='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
<div class='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
```

Instead of :

```
<div id='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
<div id='parent'> <strong> </strong> </div>
```

And your Jquery will be like:

```
$('.parent').append('Text inside div');
```

Answer (score 0):

it is already working as you want because you are using ID so it will automatically applied on first found child

```
<div id='parent'> <strong> sadsadsadsa</strong> </div>
<div id='parent'> <strong>sdsadsadadasd </strong> </div> 
$('#parent').append('Text inside div');
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/duhLnq0s/3/